# Sign in into a page using PHP

Tags: php, authentication

I have a PHP engine login page which i want to sign in using another PHP file without me physically inputting the details on that page, so i should be able to run a PHP file and sign into another login page on my server

Comment: Could you clarify, please?  I have no idea what you are asking, I'm afraid.

Comment: Does this login form of yours use GET or POST?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply have your other PHP file post the required login credentials to your login page's action url

Answer (score 2):

I'm confused, I don't know if I really understood your question! 
But if it's the case, just send the details of your login form through a post method. And in this other page you'll just check if the login & password are good and start a session for this user!

Answer (score 1):

If it's a HTTP authentication, use [cURL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) with options `CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH` and `CURLOPT_USERPWD`

Answer (score 1):

> without me physically inputting the details on that page

sounds like XSRF :P

Just duplicate the login page with the exact same form actions, method and input names and name it whatever you want and host it on your server. Does that answer the question?

Comment: I have a whole php component installed on my server, i want to automate the process of logging in to that system without changing those PHP files so my code will work with future versions of the PHP component

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this php login page is part of the same site, then should it not just be a case of setting the required session variables / cookies from your other php file? This seems pretty straightforward to me.

(Note that the above would assume that your other php file has some kind of login process - if it does not, then just set the post action to the url of the php login page).